# Not able to get values from a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an MVC project that I'm storing record ID values in hidden fields. Then when  the user updates the page I use querySelectorAll to put them all into a List. From there I need to loop through the list and call an AJAX function to update the database.

When I initially created it I used Array.from to put the objects into an Array and from there just loop through that array to call my Ajax. Thing is I found out that this does not work in IE11. I typically use Chrome but the customer base is IE11.

This is what I used to get it to work in Chrome. It gets all the hidden fields with an ID='RID', then converts to an Array, and then loop that Array.

```
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]#RID');
console.log(listItems);

var bidRID = Array.from(listItems, function (el) { return el.value })   
for (var i = 0, l = bidRID.length; i < l; i++) { 
    ....AJAX CALL....
    data: { rid: bidRID[i], prefOrder: i },
}
```

I have been searching for what I can do in IE11 and trying some different things but can't seem to figure out what to do here.

I looked at the list in the Debug tools and it's a list of hidden fields as expected. So, I thought I could possible loop through that list of objects and get the "value" but the things I've tried are coming back blank or NULL.

```
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]#RID');

for (var i = 0, l = listItems.length; i < l; i++) {
    alert(listItems[i].val);
};
```

also tried

```
for (var i = 0, l = listItems.length; i < l; i++) {
    alert(listItems[i].innerHTML);
};
```

and

```
for (var i = 0, l = listItems.length; i < l; i++) {
    alert(listItems[i].NodeValue);
};
```

Here is a screenshot of what the NodeList looks like when viewing it from the console.

[image]

Comment: Well, as id are unique your `#RID` must be wrong

Comment: You should probably use a class instead of an id there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `id`'s should be unique, second, with javascript you use `.value` to get an `input` value.

*A note, when combine `type`, `id` and attribute selector, do like this `'input#RID[type="hidden"]'`, though since `id`'s is unique one really only need the id `#RID`.*

Since they all have a `name` attribute, you can use that instead of the `id`, either combined with `[type="hidden"]` or w/o.

```
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"][name="RID"]');

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    console.log(listItems[i].value);
};
```

Stack snippet

```js
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"][name="RID"]');

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  console.log(listItems[i].value);
};
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="RID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="RID" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="RID" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="RID" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="RID" value="5">
```

---

If they for an unknown reason still have the same `id`, you can target them with the attribute selector, like this

```js
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"][id="RID"]');

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  console.log(listItems[i].value);
};
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="RID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="RID" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="RID" value="3">
<input type="hidden" id="RID" value="4">
<input type="hidden" id="RID" value="5">
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I was close but I only saw ".val" in the intelisense and not "value". However, I should have know to at least given ".value" a try with JavaScript. Your answer looks like it will work.

Comment: Also, the way MVC works with @HTML.HiddenFor, it will automatically create an ID and Name the same as the property you map it to. This is what I have in my For...Each on my Razor View. @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RID, new { Value = item.RID }) so it auto creates an ID="RID" and Name-"RID". I know with JS the ID should be unique but in the case it probably won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @Caverman It makes a difference when trying to target them with an `id` selector, and the workaround is to do `[id="RID"]`, shown in my last sample.